# Por que no me funciona un autofocus en una ventana modal?

Tags: html, bootstrap

espero puedan ayudarme, tengo una ventana modal que el autofocus funciona solo la primera vez que se usa, en las siguientes ya no, mi proyecto tiene un listado de productos y cuando selecciona el producto aparece la siguiente modal, pero solo funciona la primera vez, les muestro el codigo de la modal. quiero hacer que el autofocus funcione todas las veces que yo le de click en

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalProducto" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalProducto" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <div class="row col-md-12 text-center">
                <div class="col-md-4">Existencia</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">Precio</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">Cantidad</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body col-md-12 row center">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" v-model="existencia" class="form-control" readonly="readonly">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" v-model="pre" class="form-control" readonly="readonly">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="number" class="form-control focus" name="" autofocus v-model.number="canti" @keydown.enter.prevent="noenter">
              </div><br><br>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" v-on:click.prevent="agregarFila">Agregar</a></td>
              <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Cancelar</a></td>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Por si sirviera de algo este es el codido que llama a la modal:

```
<tbody v-show="mayus">
            <tr v-for="(producto, index) in FiltroProducto">
              <td>@{{producto.producto}}</td>
              <td>@{{producto.marca}}</td>
              <td>@{{producto.categoria.toUpperCase()}}</td>
              <td><a href="" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalProducto" @click.prevent="verProducto(producto)">+</a></td>
              <td><a href="#" @click.prevent="ver(producto)" class="btn btn-info">*</a></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
```

Comment: El atributo `autofocus` es booleano, recibe un parametro `autofocus="true"`

Answer (score 7):

El atributo `autofocus` te funciona la primera vez porque cuando cierras una modal esta lo que hace es ocultarse, no se destruye, por lo que ese autofoco no vuelve a ejecutarse una vez lo ha perdido.

La solución que se me ocurre es gestionar ese foco mediante **JQuery**. Podemos reaccionar a cuando una modal de **Bootstrap** se abre por medio de la función `on('shown.bs.modal')`, así podríamos hacer que cada vez que la modal sea abierta podamos colocar el foco en el elemento deseado.

```js
$(function () {
  $('#ModalProducto').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('.focus').focus();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="ModalProducto" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalProducto" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <div class="row col-md-12 text-center">
                <div class="col-md-4">Existencia</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">Precio</div>
                <div class="col-md-4">Cantidad</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body col-md-12 row center">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" v-model="existencia" class="form-control" readonly="readonly">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" v-model="pre" class="form-control" readonly="readonly">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="number" class="form-control focus">
              </div><br><br>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" v-on:click.prevent="agregarFila">Agregar</a></td>
              <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Cancelar</a></td>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <tbody v-show="mayus">
            <tr v-for="(producto, index) in FiltroProducto">
              <td>Nombre</td>
              <td>Marca</td>
              <td>Categoría</td>
              <td><a id="nuevo_producto" href="" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalProducto" @click.prevent="verProducto(producto)">+</a></td>
              <td><a href="#" onclick="ver(producto)" class="btn btn-info">*</a></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
```

Comment: Una pregunta, este codigo resulta al colocarlo solo así? te pregunto porque le agregue las etiquetas de script y le pegue ese codigo solo asi como lo tienes y no funciona, que podrá ser? soy novato para javascript, pero nunca he usado algo como esto "$(function ()"

Comment: `$(function () {...})` es una función de **Jquery** que se ejecuta cuando el **DOM** termina de cargarse. Se usa para no tratar de referenciar elementos que aun no están accesibles por no haber terminado de cargar. **Jquery** se trata de una librería de **Javascript**, que Bootstrap necesita para funcionar y que deberías tener cargada en un `script` del tipo que tengo yo cargados al inicio del **HTML** de mi respuesta. En la consola del navegador es posible que se te esté mostrando un error, compruébalo y me dices.

Comment: encontré este otro codigo para poder hacer lo que quiero, pero tampoco me funciona, creo que es algo mas. te mostraré                                <script type="text/javascript">
      $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        $(this).find('[autofocus]').focus();
      });
      @yield('jscript')
    </script> este yield va adjunto al archivo donde esta la ventana modal del inicio del hilo, y lo tengo hasta el final del documento, tendría que mover el yield(´jscript´) la principio para que funcione? si pudieras tal vez darme tu correo y te envio todo el codigo

Comment: Ya lo logré hacer, muchas gracias, me faltaba agregar todas las librerías que tienes en la parte de arriba del código.

Comment: ¡Me alegro! Marcar las respuestas que te sirvieron como aceptadas es una buena practica, ya que así personas con un problema similar al tuyo y que entren a la pregunta sabrán que se obtuvo una solución.